# Weird error while uploading a PNG image

Tags: bug, status-declined

Weird error while uploading a PNG image.

> For security reasons, framing is not allowed. Click OK to remove frames.

[image]

I'm just reporting this, I don't know what it means but for the context, in case it's helpful to SE:

- I was uploading a PNG image.
- The image is 2500px x 1400px, not significantly huge.
- I can view the image just fine, but it does consistently draw this error on upload.
- The error is triggered after the image has fully uploaded.

Comment: What's your image weight? I know there is a limit, but it's supposed to resize the image if it's too big. See [this meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225263/how-to-upload-bigger-size-image-with-post/225264#225264). It might have also been [reported here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133138/for-security-reasons-framing-is-not-allowed-click-ok-to-remove-the-frames-o), not sure if it's the same problem.

Comment: @Yisela It's 5MB. Converting to 1.8MB JPG fixed the issue.

Answer (score 4):

Yeah, this is a known issue; imgur won't accept large images, and the upload UI doesn't handle failure particularly gracefully.

Comment: It's creepy how fast you guys are at looking at these bug reports. On Meta.SE, seeing an SE dev jump on a bug issue "I'm taking a look at this" -- Next day: "fixed" , is kinda impressive. But an oddball bug report on some random SE site late at night? Man...

Comment: The trick is, you don't have to jump on *all* of them *all* of the time... Just enough so that folks think you're watching.

Comment: @Shog9 ahh do not tell all the IT secrets leaves  nothing to old admins like me